# Get IP addresses from PCAP file in scapy

Tags: optimization, pcap, scapy

Is there a smart and fast way to get all IP addresses from a PCAP file?
I need only (destination address, source address) tuples.

Currently I'm using Scapy's `rdpcap` function like this:

```
from scapy.all import *
pcap = rdpcap('file.pcap')

ips = set([(p[IP].fields['src'], p[IP].fields['dst']) for p in pcap if p.haslayer(IP) == 1])
```

But it takes about two minutes on my machine to parse a 70MB PCAP file with 370 unique extracted entries...

Comment: By IP packages do you mean IP Packets?

Comment: @RyPeck yes, corrected that in the question

Comment: Don't you mean the couples (source address, destination address)? Because that's what you're doing. Or may be the IP *addresses*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "best" way to do what I think (based on the code you provided, I suppose you want the couples (IP source address, IP destination address) rather than IP packets) you want is :

```
>>> set((p[IP].src, p[IP].dst) for p in PcapReader('file.pcap') if IP in p)
```

You don't waste memory with the whole PCAP file, the `set` object is built packet by packet.

If it's not fast enough, you can instruct Scapy not to dissect packets after the `IP` layer since you don't use the `IP` payload:

```
>>> IP.payload_guess = []
```

And then run the previous command.